# How to shear a cube (or rectangular cuboid) without changing surface dimensions?

Tags: mesh, transforms

Imagine a cube (or rectangular cuboid) where each sides have a depth.  Let's say like a carton box.

If you remove any two opposing sides, you can shear it to look like a rhombus or back into a square while keeping each surface dimensions.

What are easy ways to do this in Blender?

In my particular case, there are a bit more details than a carton box so I am hoping that the rest of the model can keep its appearance while shearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a GN group which will deform a mesh as you describe:

[image]

..it rotates every point in a mesh by 'Angle' about an axis in direction 'Axis Direction' passing through the projection of that point onto the XY plane at offset 'Z Offset', all in Object Space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Using Blender 3.4.1, I am not able to reproduce the exact geometry nodes.  In 'Group Input', I only get 'Z' and 'Axis', not 'Z offset' and 'Axis Direction'.  In 'Multiply Add', I only see one multiplier instead of 3.  It is my first-time using geometry nodes so perhaps it is something I don't yet understand.

Comment: Hi, @VirtualPaul ! If you download the .blend, it should work. Sure, it is a couple of things you don't yet understand. The 'Z Offset' in the _Group Input_  is one I created and named myself, by dragging a noodle from its first vacant socket. It's the way you make inputs to GN groups, the inputs either appear in the modifier panel, or on the left side of the _Group_  node if  it's nested (used as a subgroup, with Add > Group, in another GN tree).   The _Multiply Add_ node has 3 entries because it's _Vector Math_ > 'Multiply Add', not _Math_ > 'Multiply Add'.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.  Is there a way to clean-up all the fields available in the modifier section?  It shows 12 of them but the way I understand it, I only need one angle and 3 axes to control this GN?  Or perhaps I just need to delete it and redo it from scratch.

Comment: @VirtualPaul 1 angle, 1 axis-direction (vector, 3 components), 1 Z-offset. I don't know how you wind up with 12 :) Maybe look in the N panel of your GN window, under the Group tab, 'Inputs', and delete the ones you're not using? (You can also set their types there)

Answer (score 3):

There is a shear operation.  If you press f3 and type "shear" you will find it, or go to mesh>transform>shear.

If you shear the box along a local axis and then resize it along one axis, it will appear to flatten.

You can get equal sides by resizing it this way.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I just wish I would not have to scale manually and measure to get the correct result.